# why is it not possible to throw checked Exception in java 8 forEach with lambda

Tags: java, exception, foreach, lambda, java-8

I have a scenario in which I want to **abort the entire progress** if any of the iterated objects have some certain bad condition (not valid or whatever). **I don't want to just skip this specific object** and go on with the rest.

As an example take reading a CSV file. If one of the lines have less/more elements than the header line, I will have problems mapping it. I then want to abort the process with an exception "csv file is invalid" which I catch in higher level to react properly.

I use something like this:

```
csvLines.forEach(line -> {
    if (line.isValid()) {
        doSomethingWith(line);
    } else {
        // ABORT MISSION, I REPEAT, ABORT!
        // throw new CSVNotValidException("did not work :(");
    }
});
```

I saw many SO posts regarding "jumping out of J8 foreach", but in there I only see how to extend the standard behavior etc. to somehow make it possible.

**I want to know, *why* it is designed this way, that no checked Exception can be thrown (and catched in higher level afterwards) within a lambda expression in Java 8**

I know technically, why this is the case (the functional interfaces simply don't define the throws part), but I don't understand, *why* it is chosen so. I only could explain this to myself, if you can solve all issues without the *need of throwing an exception* - but I don't actually think that this is the case.

P.S.: I don't want to use a RuntimeException (which would be possible to throw) as I don't like catching RuntimeExceptions. I want to use a checked Exception for this.

Comment: Because checked exceptions are now uncool.

Comment: Thanks Tunaki, somehow I didn't see this SO post, as the answer there is what I searched and expected: It's rather a bug than a feature. Not what I hoped, but I'm pleased. How can I close this as a duplicate?

Comment: It's already closed as a dup.

Comment: The question has it backwards.  It's not that we made a decision to do something special against checked exceptions in lambdas -- a lambda can throw any checked exception that the corresponding functional interface method permits, just like an anon class or a named subclass.  What we did not do is decide to give lambdas *special permission* to do things with checked exceptions that other code that implements the same interface is not allowed to do.

Comment: @BAER Sorry, whatever post made you conclude this is a "bug" is incorrect.  Others may want to declare this a bug or a failure, or may disagree with the design decisions behind the way things are, but its a leap of fantasy from there to "bug".

Comment: @BrianGoetz A broken specification is a bug is a bug is a bug. And when we can't simply replace `for`-loops with `forEach`-lambdas, the specification is broken because it significantly decreases the applicability of existing APIs in the context of functional programming and leaves far too much to be desired.